# dict.get() always return None

Tags: python, dictionary, get, tuples

i have dict that key= tuple,
i have loop that every iteration i am trying to insert new tuple- if it is not exists already in the dict.
i am using the 'get' function to see if it exists so i'll get the value if not i'll get None.
the issue is that always i am getting None - although this tuple(key) is exists in the dict.
this is my code :

```
features_dict = dict()
for index, row in unique_data_frame.iterrows():
    file_name = row['SourceFile']
    feature_tuple = (row['FeatureIpName'], row['FeatureGroupName']
                     , row['FeatureName'], feature_file_id)
    last_inserted_feature_id = features_dict.get(feature_tuple)
    if last_inserted_feature_id is None:
        features_dict[feature_tuple] = last_inserted_feature_id
```

Comment: How do you know a key already exists ? Did you print the dict at each iteration and the tuple?

Comment: when i debugged it i see. the result was dict with a lot of key the same.

Comment: That is impossible, there should be a difference. Could you paste that ?

Comment: {(nan, 'FM', 'GCC - borrowing for soft bits', Decimal('2952')): Decimal('25600770'),
 (nan, 'FM', 'GCC - borrowing for soft bits', Decimal('2952')): Decimal('25600770'), 
(nan, 'FM', 'GCC - borrowing for soft bits', Decimal('2952')): Decimal('25600770')}

Comment: although when i delete the (decimal) still get this issue. any idea?